# Question mark in oracle procedure is not getting executed

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g, dynamic-sql

```
 create or replace procedure user_modification (v_user in VARCHAR2, v_pwd in VARCHAR2) IS
user_name VARCHAR2 (20) :=v_user;
pwd VARCHAR2 (20) :=v_pwd;
Begin
--logic would be here
stat:= 'ALTER USER' || user_name || 'IDENTIFIED BY ||' pwd' ||'' ;
```

Since the password is `=TEat?`, it's throwing 911 error in ORACLE SQL Developer. Please help here.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full error message. What's a "911" error?

Comment: Also show the actual code you are running; this won't even compile because the quotes are wrong, and would get ORA-00940 before ORA-00911 because spaces are missing. (And `stat` isn't declared, and you haven't included the `execute immediate` part...). I might also be useful to show exactly how you are calling the procedure, and the full exception stack you get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enclose your password in double quotes, e.g.:

```
stat:= 'ALTER USER ' || user_name || ' IDENTIFIED BY "' || pwd || '"';
```

(I've also corrected your use of single quotes, as they were incorrectly placed in your example code.)

---

ETA: [here's an example db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2cfad9491c05f2217b7b357611126134) that demonstrates code that would work if you had privileges to create users.

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried that but it doesn't work also I have tried with \ pwd\. Both does not work

Comment: @Deansql If you output before executing, what you see. stat:= 'ALTER USER' || user_name || 'IDENTIFIED BY "' || pwd || '"';
dbms_output.put_line(stat)

Comment: I see the below

Comment: ALTER USER AAA_TEST IDENTIFIED BY TEat?

Comment: When I see the log in audit table it says ALTER USER AAA_TEST IDENTIFIED BY TEat? -911 No data found for user : AAA_TEST

Comment: @Deansql - that is not what the code in this answer produces. (It would have thrown ORA-00940 originally, with missing spaces added it works as expected). Is that log entry from your original attempt, not this code?

Comment: Correct Alex, my mistake. Post compiling the procedure it shows below in the audit table

Comment: ALTER USER AAA_TEST IDENTIFIED BY  ¦¦ "TEat?" - 922 No data found for user

Comment: @Deansql - then you still aren't actually running the code in the answer, you've inserted a spurious `||` somehow.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable contribution, its working with quotes now.